# employees.map is not a function randomly while fetching from Spring Boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-hooks

This is my fetch

```
const [employees, setEmployees] = React.useState([

])

useEffect(() => {
fetch('http://192.168.0.7:8000/employee/list')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => setEmployees(json))

}, [employees])
```

I have employees as parameter so I can fetch constantly and listen for updates without reloading.

Everytime I make a POST or DELETE request, or if I reload the page fast too many times, this seems to happen. if I remove employees from dependencies, it doesn't happen anymore. How do I prevent this from continuously happening, even when my backend crashes or runs into errors?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Will you share the definition of setEmployees and useEffect

Comment: You initiate an infinite loop by adding employees as a dependency, as `useEffect` runs every time `employees` updates. So you fetch employees set them `useEffect` runs again you fetch it again...

Comment: I want to run useEffect everytime employees updates, so how do I avoid that?

Comment: you can create a state which will notify if the employees record is changed and use that state as a dependency instead of employees to prevent the infinite rerender loop

Comment: Can you show me how to do that?